# 8 digit hex rgba value

Tags: hex, rgba

I am working with a piece of code that requires me to use 8 digit hex rgba values

```
-b [ --background-color ] arg (=efefefff) color of background in hex rgba
-f [ --foreground-color ] arg (=00000000) color of background in hex rgba
```

I cant for the life of me figure out what the 8 digit combination for black is

```
00000000
```

is completely transparent not black

can some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Black has no red, green or blue, but it is not transparent, so the alpha needs to be `ff`. Therefore the combination you seek is

```
000000ff
```

Comment: 8-digit hex might be ARGB, in which case black would be ff000000.

Comment: @Jesdisciple Question refers to rgba.

Comment: I wasn't disputing your answer, but I found this question before I knew ARGB existed. My hex was ARGB, so that's a post-it to myself or anyone else in a similar situation.